# How to test if system-name matches a string in .emacs with Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

How to test if system-name matches a string in .emacs with Emacs Lisp? I expect my `system-name` will be something like `userhost-122-1`. The characters after the first dash will be varying. So I am looking for a boolean elisp function that returns true iff the system-name for the current Emacs session has a value starting with `userhhost`. How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Easy:

```
(string-match "\\`userhost" system-name)
```

Comment: "\\`" matches only at the beginning of the string (`system-name`). Backslashes in Lisp strings need to be doubled. See the Elisp manual, node `Regexp Backslash` (for "\\`") and `Regexp Special` (for double "\").

Answer (score 0):

(search-forward system-name nil t)